# Can you populate a vector of vectors anonymously in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++, I wanted to make a vector of vectors that each contains ints. Currently I have to do something like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectors;
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
```

then

```
vectors.push_back(v1);
vectors.push_back(v2);
```

In java you can skip declaring v1 and v2, just initialize the vector containing the other vectors, then make a loop or something that just does

```
myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<int>());
```

Can you do this in C++? If so, how? Thanks

Edit: also, what is this called, when you add an anonymous/unnamed object? I used the term "anonymous" to refer to an unnamed vector, or in the java example, an unnamed new arraylist object. I'm sure there's a term for it, but I didn't know what it was so I couldn't search it on google.

Comment: You can simply `vectors.resize(2)`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler why? there is constructor overload that accepts count - `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectors(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is an Object without a variable
In java, we use `new ArrayList<Integer>()`.
In C++, we use `std::vector<int>()`.
This works, because in C++, theoretically we can say

```cpp
std::vector<int> my_vector = std::vector<int>();
```

The above code is functionally equivalent to `std::vector<int>my_vector;` because C++ calls the constructor automatically.  The reason C++ does this is because C++ has no `null` type, unlike Java.

So this becomes:

```cpp
vectors.push_back(std::vector<int>());
```

PS.

Java objects = C++ pointers.  C++ pointers have the value `nullptr` or `0`, Java objects have the default value `null`.

EDIT:
Nico Schertler has an interesting solution you should take a look at as well.  I'm not going to include them in my answer so he can make an answer out of it if he wants, but take a look at his comment.

Comment: Note that prior to C++11, `vectors.push_back(std::vector<int>());` will construct a temp `vector<int>` and then make a copy of it for the push.  In C++11 and later, it will move the temp as-is instead of copy it. To avoid the temp altogether, you could use `vectors.resize(vectors.size()+1);` instead, or in C++11 and later, `vectors.emplace_back();`